# Getting Error when using AJAX

Tags: ajax, server, client

when i send data to server using ajax its outputting an error rather than success despite the fact that the data is being received by the server. Im just wondering what i'm doing wrong?

client side

```
$( "#PlotBtn" ).click(function() { 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/data',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: data0,
    success: function() { 
    console.log('success'); 
    $("#graph1").attr('src', $("#graph1").attr('src') + '?' + Math.random() );
    $("#graph1").css('visibility', 'visible');},
    error: function() { console.log('error');}
    });
});
```

server side

```
    pp.post("/data", function (req, res) {
       console.log('data: ');
       var data2 = req.body;
       console.log(data2); here
});
```

Comment: You are using JS for server?

Comment: It would be usefull if you share your error!

Comment: Can you say what the error is specifically please?

Comment: In your error callback you can pass an arg to get the error

Comment: You should read docs before you ask  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ there is explained how to use error callback

Comment: Yeah im using js for the server. Its that error message that i created.